# Casting Backbone Collection object to its original type

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I use backbone js to add custom elements to a backbone js Collection . I need to cast it back to its original type below is the

```
var Text = function () {

};

var Radio = function () {

};

function myfunction() {
    var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
    var t = new Text();
    var r = new Radio();
    collection.add(t);
    collection.add(r);

    alert(t instanceof Text);
    alert(collection.at(0) instanceof Text);

}
```

The statement `alert(t instanceof Text);` returns true where as the statement

```
alert(collection.at(0) instanceof Text); returns false .
```

Is there any way i could cast it to its original type ?

Comment: actually it is better to add backbone models to a backbone collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

- `collection.add(t)` is equivalent to `collection.add(new Backbone.Model(t))` when `t` does not inherit `Backbone.Model`<sup>1</sup>
- `Backbone.Model`'s constructor copies the attributes of `t` into the new object via [`Model.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) but does not keep any other information on the source object<sup>2</sup>

If you can, extend `Backbone.Model` to build `Text` and `Radio`

```
var Text = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
```

If not, you will have to add additional information in your attributes to identify the correct prototypes.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Annotated source code, Collection._prepareModel](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-124)
<sup>2</sup> [Annotated source code, Model.set](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-51)

Comment: Actually the controls Text and Radio inherit from the Backbone.View. What i need is a collections of different views

Comment: It does not change my answer, views don't inherit from models. You could also pass a wrapper instead of the view : `{view: aText}, {view: aRadio} ` and so on